# SQL returns search even though check should not

Tags: java, sql

I have the following query :

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE   year = 11 AND orderDate LIKE ? OR  orderNo LIKE ? OR  prodNo LIKE ? OR  prodName LIKE ? OR  inquiryDate LIKE ? OR  confirmDate LIKE ? OR  deliveryLT LIKE ? OR  deliveryRiis LIKE ? OR  signsPrice LIKE ? OR  vrPrice LIKE ? OR  deliveryPrice LIKE ? OR  unexpectPrice LIKE ? OR  riisBonus LIKE ? OR  kennBonus LIKE ? OR  profit LIKE ? OR  profitPercent LIKE ? OR  quantity LIKE ?;
```

The problem is, even though the column year is not 11, I still receive the data, is it because I use OR ? (The question marks are used because I use preparedStatements).

When I do

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE   year = 11 AND orderDate LIKE ? ;
```

It works fine, so am I correct in assuming it is the OR? If so, how can I solve it? I want one of those to be true and year to be 100% true;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; AND is processed before `OR`, so you're essentially querying for all projects where `year = 11 and orderDate LIKE ?` or if any of the other conditions are met.

You need to use parentheses in order to make clear which conditions apply to the `AND` and which should be `OR`ed.

I would assume that you want it to look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE   year = 11 AND (orderDate LIKE ? OR  orderNo LIKE ? OR  prodNo LIKE ? OR  prodName LIKE ? OR  inquiryDate LIKE ? OR  confirmDate LIKE ? OR  deliveryLT LIKE ? OR  deliveryRiis LIKE ? OR  signsPrice LIKE ? OR  vrPrice LIKE ? OR  deliveryPrice LIKE ? OR  unexpectPrice LIKE ? OR  riisBonus LIKE ? OR  kennBonus LIKE ? OR  profit LIKE ? OR  profitPercent LIKE ? OR  quantity LIKE ?)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I was not aware of that part of the syntax..makes sense though, I'll try it now, will return with result. works perfectly, thank you so much. I will accept in 9 minutes when I am allowed to, you were so fast :D

Answer (score 1):

The [SQL rules of precedence](http://akdora.wordpress.com/2009/02/18/rules-of-precedence-in-sql-where-clause/) state that "and" comes before "or", so your SQL is equivalent to:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE ( year = 11 AND orderDate LIKE ? ) OR  orderNo LIKE ?
OR  prodNo LIKE ? OR  prodName LIKE ? OR  inquiryDate LIKE ?
```

Override it with added parentheses to fit your requirements:

```
SELECT * FROM project WHERE   year = 11 AND
 (orderDate LIKE ? OR  orderNo LIKE ?
  OR  prodNo LIKE ? OR  prodName LIKE ? OR  inquiryDate LIKE ?)
```